# KubernetesPodOperator failing with Forbidden

Tags: python, kubernetes, docker-compose, airflow, airflow-webserver

I am running a `KubernetesPodOperator` as below:

```
with DAG(DAG_NAME, default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None) as dag:
    start_task = DummyOperator(task_id='start_task')


    k8s_task = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace=namespace,
                              image="python:3.6",
                              cmds=["python","-c"],
                              arguments=["print('hello world')"],
                              labels={"foo": "bar"},
                              name="airflow-test-pod",
                              task_id="passing-task",
                              in_cluster=False,
                              config_file='/include/.kube/config',
                              is_delete_operator_pod=True,
                              get_logs=True,
                              dag=dag
                              )
```

The `config_file` is copied from my local machine using `- .kube/config:/opt/airflow/include/.kube/config` in the `webserver` service section of the `docker-compose`.

However, when I run the task, I get a failure with the following stacktrace:

```
Reason: Forbidden
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': 'ba9f64ae-c40b-4c66-8ce8-a0b546667468', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid': 'be9df35b-0e2e-4c70-9b35-14be91d563e0', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid': '2ccf40a9-54c8-47b4-8e83-d87415d5fc9a', 'Date': 'Fri, 25 Mar 2022 10:30:28 GMT', 'Content-Length': '375'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"pods \"***-test-pod.facbe86a27ac400ab37506ea73ac45d5\" is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot patch resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"default\"","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"name":"***-test-pod.facbe86a27ac400ab37506ea73ac45d5","kind":"pods"},"code":403}
```

I have tried checking other questions, but none seems to be helping. Anyone know what I am doing wrong? TIA

Comment: Since you haven't provided the namespace parameter in the kubernetes pod operator, it is trying to deploy the pod in default namespace of the kubernetes cluster. Now you may not have the permission to create a pod in default namespace. Confirm the namespace where you have permissions and add that as a parameter in the KubernetesPodOperator(namespace=my_namespace)